# Why would you ever want to use 'int index = min_element(vector.begin(), vector.end()) - vector.begin();' (c++)

Tags: c++

I found some c++ code that I would like to understand. In this code they use

```
int airplane = min_element(min_cost_airplane.begin(),
min_cost_airplane.end()) - min_cost_airplane.begin();
```

But I don't know what this line of code exactly accomplishes. `min_cost_airplane` is a vector. I understand the min_element function, but I can't wrap my head around the -vector.begin at the end. Is the structure of this line of code common used? The thing I understand is that this line of code returns an iterator to the smallest element in the vector minus an iterator to the first element of the vector. So what does the iterator point to?
Can someone please help me?

Comment: what did you not understand when consulting [some documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) ?

Answer (score 3):

The [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) algorithm returns an **iterator**. You can dereference that iterator to access the "minimum" element of the container. If, instead, you want to know the **index** of the element you need to compute it as the distance from the beginning of the container.

For random-access iterators you can subtract the iterators to get the offset, or index value. That's what your example does. There's also a [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) function that computes the index but it also works for non-random access iterators. For example:

```
auto iter = std::min_element(min_cost_airplane.begin(), min_cost_airplane.end());
int index = std::distance(min_cost_airplane.begin(), iter);
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::min_element` returns an *iterator* to the first instance of the minimum value in the given range.

`begin` returns an *iterator* to the first element in the container.

The `std::vector` iterators are special (it's a *random access iterator*) in that you can subtract one from another which yields the distance between them in terms of elements (it's pointer arithmetic under the hood). To be more generic and clearer, write

```
auto airplane = std::distance(
    min_cost_airplane.begin(),
    std::min_element(min_cost_airplane.begin(), min_cost_airplane.end())
);
```

Comment: nitpick: it isnt `std::vector`s iterators that are special, but all random access iterators support `-`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: Yes, it's worth adding that in.

Answer (score -3):

`std::min_element` is used to finds the smallest element in the range [first, last].

```
std::vector<int> v{3, 8, 4, 2, 5, 9};
 
std::vector<int>::iterator result = std::min_element(v.begin(), v.end());
 //result iterator to the minimum value in vector v.
std::cout << "min element is: " << *result;
```

output: min element is: 2

Note : The smallest value in vector v is 2.

Comment: This is not the answer, because the result of the line in the question is offset, not a minimal element.

Comment: OPs code finds the index of the min element, not the value

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Perhaps you can explain what you get when you subtract `begin()` from `result`.

Comment: OK but i am telling the use of `std::min_element` because i thought he is confuse in algorithm.

Comment: explaining something else than the code actually does might be confusing ;)

Comment: I am not explaining some thing else, it is exactly what he asked befor edit:).

Comment: OP wrote in the question `I understand the min_element function`, but not what is next to the function. So, your answer only explains stuff, which OP already knows.

Comment: Firstly his question question was not so clear, after third edit it is clear now but i answered to the first one. May be little bit confusion.

Comment: already the original question was not using the value of the minimum element, but its index. Nevermind, just saying